# Accidental deletion of system files?

Tags: windows-xp

I accidentally deleted WUDFHost.exe and several associated files beginning with WUDF, due to having misread info about the files.  I thought that they were spyware.

What should I do?  I thought there was a way to check my windows system files against an online database?  Something I can type into the run box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SFC /scannow](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/system_file_checker.mspx?mfr=true) command from a command prompt (elevated Command Prompt in Vista/7/8) to check critical files against backups Windows made

Comment: @Moab That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: However, there's a switch to make this against an online database as opposed to vs a cd?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is the bad part of SFC in XP, which was corrected in Vista and later, it is best to use a XP cd with sp3, then do a reboot and manual windows update after SFC has completed.